# tar/ntfs/linux permissions

Tags: permissions, tar, ntfs

I want to backup my windows 7 partition on a dual boot system.  I'd like to do the backup from the linux side so the windows files can't change during backup.  I have a backup drive formatted in ntfs for this purpose.  Can anyone tell me if

```
cd windows_partition_root;
tar cfp - . | (cd backup_ntfs_partition; tar xvfp -)
```

will preserve my windows ntfs permissions?

Comment: My first instinct is: Yes, permissions will be preserved. The `-p` flag in `tar` preserves permissions.

Comment: `dd` or a partition-imaging tool will serve you better for this task.  note when using `tar` the `-p` flag behavior is very different between BSD `tar` and GNU `tar`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no, a backup of an NTFS partition made under Linux won't restore permissions properly. NTFS can encode access control lists that Linux doesn't support; the [NTFS-3g documentation](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/#options) gives some information about what is supported. As far as I know, Windows does use ACL that Linux doesn't support, at least in some setups (though maybe not on the low-end “home” editions).